# Install Gitosis without creating a new user

Tags: git, gitosis, gitolite

I have an ssh account but do not have root access and hence cannot create a new user. Is it possible for me to install gitosis or gitolite on this account?

If not, is there any other git server that I can install without root access?

Edit:
My issue here is in creating another user. Can I use gitosis or gitolite without creating a new user? Can I use my existing account and use both git and do normal ssh login?

(I've changed the topic accordingly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to install it locally in your home directory. Create a bin directory. When you compile it use `--prefix=$HOME` when u run `./configure`. If you are building a binary package, look in man for how to install locally. Also, Google is good resource

Comment: I can install locally. All the docs say I need to make a new system user. Just found out that I don't.

Comment: Try connecting using the verbose flag to see exactly what is causing the login to fail.  "ssh -v username@hostname"  Typically it's a key mismatch which is indicated by "public key failure"  If the keys are good make sure the permissions on the keys are 600 (locally) and that authorized_keys on the host is set to 600 as well.  Both of these are under $HOME/.ssh

Comment: It's giving PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

Answer (score 1):

Please use Gitolite instead as Gitosis is no longer actively developed. And, yes, you can do an install from the client side. You should not need root access.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I've updated the question and title. Hope my question is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

With gitolite installed, the 'gitolite users' appear in the ~myusername/.ssh/authorized_users file as public keys with "command=" lines surrounded by comments marking the gitolite users, vis.

```
# gitolite start
command="/usr/bin/gl-auth-command gituser1",no-port-forwarding,...,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAA...TwQw==
# gitolite end
```

Any key you put *outside* those comments, won't be touched by the gitolite update process, i.e. add your normal login public key either above the `#gitolite start` or below the `#gitolite end` and the user of that key will log in as normal and pushing the gitolite-admin repo won't overwrite it.